# Cannot quit iTunes in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, itunes

Every time I try to quit iTunes (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) in OS X lion I encounter some strange problem and after some seconds I find it has run itself again!

If I use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> I see iTunes in my running application.

Why could be causing this and how do I stop it?

Comment: Did you try to reboot?

Comment: Of course, I have this Problem since I get My New MBP with Lion(10.7.0) installed in it, Also I update to 10.7.1 and still have the problem. Maybe if I update to 10.7.2 the problem will be solved or not :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve experienced that kind of behavior from iTunes when an application keeps a connection to iTunes’ AppleScript interface open – whenever iTunes tries to quit, the open connection forces a restart. Are you running any kind of tool or app accessing iTunes? Menu bar control apps, sync solutions, or maybe an audioscrobbler? If yes, try to quit that first and see if iTunes quits cleanly after that.

Comment: I use "I love Star"(http://i-love-stars.en.softonic.com/mac) and as you said that was my problem, but I have used this software in snow leopard and didn't have this problem there. I think it's not fully compatible with Lion.

Comment: any clever tips for finding this application from the command line if you are unsure which it is?

Comment: Nope, but that would be an excellent question to ask on site.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your iTunes installation is screwed up.

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=4045) to uninstall iTunes, it involves

- killing it using **Activity Monitor**
- Moving it to the Trash
- Moving the related `plist` to the Trash.
- Rebooting.

Then go [**there**](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) to download the latest version and install it.

Once you have done that, see if it's still behaving. Then can (should) update to 10.7.2.

Comment: maybe this solution solve my problem, but I am not comfortable with uninstalling my iTunes :( I have large library of musics and my iTunes save many info about them like what rate I put on them or how many times I listen specific music. When I uninstall my iTunes and install new one I lost all of these MetaData :(

Comment: No, you don't. All that information is stored inside your Music/iTunes in your home folder. I have migrated my iTunes library many times and never had issues.

Comment: sounds good, in my free time I test this solution, thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this problem, the keyboard shortcut is working fine for me. (iTunes 10.5/141 and Lion 10.7.2).

However, check to ensure iTunes is not in 32-bit mode:

- Navigate to iTunes in your Applications folder.
- Click on iTunes, File -> Get Info
- Ensure "Open in 32-bit mode" is not enabled

Failing that there will surely be something printed to Console.app (Found in Applications/Utilities). Open that application and provide and relevant information that is printed to Console.